# C++, matrix operations, problem with operators

Tags: c++, matrix, operators

There is a part of my class for matrix operations:

```
class Matrix
{
private:
    std::vector < std::vector <T> > items;      
    const unsigned int rows_count;          
    const unsigned int columns_count;       

public:
    Matrix ( unsigned int m_rows, unsigned int m_columns);
    Matrix ( const Matrix <T> &M );

    template <typename U>
    Matrix <T> & operator = ( const Matrix <U> &M );

    template <typename U>
    bool operator == ( const Matrix <U> &M ) const;

    template <typename U>
    bool operator != ( const Matrix <U> &M ) const ;

    template <typename U>
    Matrix <T> operator + ( const Matrix <U> &M ) const
    ...
};
```

where

```
template <typename T>
template <typename U>
Matrix <U> Matrix <T> ::operator + ( const Matrix <U> &M ) const
{
    Matrix <U> C ( M );

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < rows_count; i++ )
    {
        for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < M.getColumnsCount(); j++ )
        {
                C ( i, j ) = items[i][j] + M.items[i][j];
        }
    }

    return C;
}

template<class T>
Matrix <T> :: Matrix ( const Matrix <T> &M )
    : rows_count ( M.rows_count ), columns_count ( M.columns_count ), items ( M.items ) {}
```

But there is a problem with the following operators:  `=`, `==`, `!=`

I am trying to assign matrix A

```
Matrix <double> A (2,2);
Matrix <double> C (2,2);
```

to the matrix B

```
Matrix <int> B (2,2);

B = A;  //Compiler error, see bellow, please
```

where A and B have different types. The same situation occurs for common matrix operations

```
C = A + B   //Compiler error, see bellow, please
```

but the compiler shows this error:

```
Error   23  error C2446: '!=' : no conversion from 'const Matrix<T> *' to 'Matrix<T> *const '
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: You didn't actually post the implementation to any of the functions that yields an error.

Comment: @DeadMG: There was a typo in operator + code, I corrected it...

Comment: The error messages make references to pointers which are totally absent of your provided code.  Note that `const Matrix<T> *` is equivalent to `Matrix<T> const*` not to `Matrix<T> *const`.

Comment: @AProgrammer: Thanks for your comment... But how to fix it, could I ask you for a short code sample?

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in the code that you presented, but you should work out the pieces of code that you present, as the error seems to point to a use of `operator!=`, while the code uses `operator=` and `operator+`.

Now as of some particular issues: You are declaring a defining different operators:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
...
   template <typename U>
   Matrix<T> operator+( Matrix<U> const & ) const; 
   //     ^
};
template <typename T>
template <typename U>
Matrix<U> Matrix<X>::operator+( Matrix<U> const & m ) const
//     ^
```

Also, in general, it is easier to define template members inside the class declaration as a rule of thumb. This is really not related to the problem that you have, but before you actually get around to providing the exact error, with the error line and the code involved (also note that it is better if you can reproduce the error in a line that does not use more than one of your defined operators)... well, without any more details I cannot really help much.

Comment: Another problem is C ( i, j ) = items[i][j] + M.items[i][j];
 when surely C.items[i][j] = ... is intended.

Comment: Saying that you solved the problem in a different operator (than the one you were having the problem to start with) is of almost no help. You should at the very least provide what the problem and the solution were, so that others looking through SO can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted it's difficult to know what the problem is since you don't provide the implementation of the case that's producing the error, '!=', nor that of '='.  My guess is that the problem arises from your const data members.  This may result in the compiler interpreting all instances of your Matrix class as const objects, which would lead to your error message.  Certainly iF your assignment operator does not take this into account, then any assignment will fail, though such code probably wouldn't compile and yours does.

So: take out the consts and see what happens.

Also,

```
C ( i, j ) = items[i][j] + M.items[i][j]
```

should surely be

```
C.items[i][i] = items[i][j] + M.items[i][j]
```

Comment: That is the problem with questions that have only half of the code. I was assuming that since `items` is private, he might have provided `operator()(int,int)` (or something similar) for member access and he would be using that. But at the end of the day, both sides of the assignment should look similar (either both `[][]` or both `(,)`)